# Restreaming live stream with Python + OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have a script that uses CaptureFromFile to get frames from a live stream, then does some work on it. Now I would like to annotate that stream and restream it - what would be the easiest way of accomplishing this? Would it be possible to somehow use the in-built VideoWriter to make a live stream as opposed to just making a video? (The resulting stream does not need to have any audio.)